# Utilizar Linha de Comandos com C#

Tags: c#, cmd, openssl, linha-de-comando

No meu trabalho eu uso o Linha de Comandos, e queria melhorar o trabalho na minha empresa. Para fazer isso, pensei em criar um programa em C# para as pessoas que não sabem trabalhar com linha de comando.

Pensei em colocar um botão para abrir um arquivo *CNF*, e com um outro botão (embutia o comando), e salvava em arquivo *CSR* no Desktop.

Ou seja, o botão iria abrir o linha de comando e colocava a seguinte fórmula:

```
cd desktop
openssl -req -new -config cert.cnf -out "cert.csr" out.
```

Ou seja, o ficheiro *myfile.csr* estará no ambiente de trabalho, e através da linha de comandos, irá modificar para *myfile.cnf*.

Sugestões?

Comment: E isto é necessário? O .Net possui uma infraestrutura completa que até supera o que o OpenSSL faz de forma bem integrada com todo o ecossistema.

Comment: Desculpe se sou burro demais, mas eu não consigo entender como é que isso pode ajudar alguém a trabalhar com o OpenSSL.

Comment: Poderia explicar exatamente o fluxo de processo que sua ferramenta deverá ter? Sinto que falta alguma coisa.

Comment: @VictorStafusa no meu local de trabalho, existem mulheres que não sabem usar o OpenSSL. O que eu queria fazer era o seguinte: Um Windows Forms, com 2 botões. O 1º serve para ir buscar o ficheiro "csr" e o 2º botão é para gravar o ficheiro em "cnf". Mas para isso, o OpenSSL teria que estar a ser executado, sem que as pessoas se apercebessem, percebeu?

Comment: @bigown alguma ajuda?

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida/problema afinal? O que você tentou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma variante do código [postado pelo Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59449/6454):

```
public void ExecutarComandoSSL(string arquivoCNF, string arquivoCSR) {
    using (System.Diagnostics.Process processo = new System.Diagnostics.Process()) {
        processo.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("comspec");
        processo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        processo.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c openssl req -new -config {0} -out \"{1}\"", arquivoCNF, arquivoCSR);

        //processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processo.Start();
        processo.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

**Nota**: O comando executará no diretório da área de trabalho do usuário atual. [**Informações**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.specialdirectories.aspx).

1. Faça o seguinte, no formulário, coloque:

   - Dois botões, um para buscar o arquivo *CNF*, e outro para salvar no formato *CSR*.
   - Coloque um componente [`OpenFileDialog`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog).
2. Crie uma classe para resgatar e guardar as informações sobre os arquivos:

   ```
   public static class VariaveisGlobais 
   {
       public static string CNF { get; set; }
       public static string CSR { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. No botão responsável por buscar o arquivo *CNF*, coloque:

   ```
   DialogResult resposta = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
   if (resposta == DialogResult.OK) {
        string arquivo = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        VariaveisGlobais.CNF = arquivo;
        VariaveisGlobais.CSR = "cert.csr"; // Leia a sugestão
   }
   ```

   **Sugestão**: Você pode utilizar o componente [`SaveFileDialog`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog) para permitir ao usuário salvar o arquivo no local de sua preferência.
4. No botão responsável por salvar o arquivo no formato *CSR*, coloque:

   ```
   string arquivoCNF = VariaveisGlobais.CNF;
   string arquivoCSR = VariaveisGlobais.CSR;

   // Aqui você poderia tratar o conteúdo das variáveis
   ExecutarComandoSSL(arquivoCNF, arquivoCSR);
   ```

Comment: Amigo @qmechanik, fiz o programa com esse código em cima indicado, porém o processo.StartInfo.Arguments mas este não está a enviar o conteúdo para a Linha de Comandos. Posso enviar para si o programa?

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Pode detalhar melhor o que esta havendo? Eu não cheguei a testar o código, experimente trocar o `/C` por `/K` na linha onde define-se os argumentos.

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Conseguiu depurar o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Amigo @qmechanik, ainda não pude, pois tenho tido muito trabalho. Esta semana que vem, irei tentar arranjar tempo.

Comment: Amigo @qmechanik não está a funcionar...

Comment: @GodfatherSantana O que exatamente aconteceu? retirei um `"` a mais que tinha no código da função `ExecutarComandoSSL`, verifique também a sintaxe onde passa os argumentos, se está correta.

Comment: A funcionar o que pretendia amigo @qmechanik, obrigado!

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Se possível marque a resposta como aceite. =)

Answer (score 6):

Você quer fazer o mesmo procedimento do `cmd` dentro de um aplicativo escrito em c#? Se é isto, então você pode usar `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Você terá que unir o comando `cd` com o `openssl` usando o `&`, veja um exemplo:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

//Oculta cmd
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

//Chama CMD
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

//seu comando
startInfo.Arguments = "/C cd Desktop& openssl \"myfile.csr\" -req -new -config myfile.cnf out.";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Para simplificar você pode passar os argumentos pelo `Start()`, conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973631/1518921):

```
const string strCmdText = "/C cd Desktop& openssl \"myfile.csr\" -req -new -config myfile.cnf out.";
...
process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Comment: Amigo @GuilhermeNascimento, ajuda bastante, porém o "myfile.csr" tem que mudar, consoante o nome do arquivo. É possível? Editei a fórmula.

Comment: @GodfatherSantana Você pode formatar a *string* com o `.Format()`. Algo como: `startInfo.Arguments = "/C cd Desktop& openssl \"{0}\" -req -new -config myfile.cnf out.".format(variavelCSR);`.

Comment: @qmechanik, não entendi onde irei colocar essa linha de código. Visto que irei buscar o ficheiro com um button, o código que o Guilherme Nascimente me deixou é para o button save?

Comment: @GodfatherSantana pensei que sua dificuldade era com a linha de comando, mas vejo agora que você está com dificuldade no desenvolvimento todo (desde selecionar o arquivo até passa-lo para a linha de comando), assim que tiver um tempo tento postar um exemplo funcional.

Comment: Obrigado, aguardarei @GuilhermeNascimento.

Answer (score 0):

Sei que é tarde, mas vi o tópico e achei interessante, pois passei pelo mesmo ontem
E para quem estiver a passar pelo mesmo pode solucionar da seguinte forma:

```
string executavelSSL = "\"C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\openssl.exe\"";

Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // Não preciso
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + "ponha aqui seu caminho");
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(executavelSSL + " -req -new -config cert.cnf -out \"cert.csr\" out");
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

quando o caminho do openssl não está nas variáveis de ambiente (e mesmo que esteja), no código eu recomendo passar o caminho do .exe (`"C:\caminho_onde_está_instalado\bin\openssl.exe "`) em vez de `openssl` pois tive alguns problemas com isso.

Nesse caso o comando resultante será: `"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" -req -new -config cert.cnf -out "cert.csr" out`;